# Can Ubuntu live CD help to recover if I move partitions?

Tags: grub2, gparted

I read [this doc of gparted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem) to recover from booting issues when a partition is moved.

There it mentions under the heading `Fixing GRUB boot problem`, how to do. It says to run `grub` command from gparted terminal and run the necessary commands. I haven't yet confirmed how it works but I'm on my way to do that.

I would like to know whether installing grub using Ubuntu live CD can solve my purpose. Earlier I had always successfully able to recover from booting problems using live CD. Now this is the 1st time I'm moving my /boot partitions and a few other partitions of Ubuntu installed on my hard disk. Can live CD help here also?

Comment: there was no gparted terminal.Please tell what's your actual problem is?

Comment: He's referring to GParted live-usb, methinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided in your question is dealing with **GRUB Legacy** not **GRUB2**.

But of course, you should be able to solve any boot problems by using a live CD.

Comment: Any boot problem!! Great! Just I would like your confirmation once again that: I would be shortly moving my ubuntu OS partitions including boot partition using gparted. Now using Ubuntu live CD, if I only re-install GRUB that should work and make my OS again bootable !! (addressing this to @Jo-Erlend Schinstad also). I ask this again because that link talks of 'stage1' and 'stage 2' even.

Comment: First: Are you using Grub Legacy or Grub2? Grub2 has no such as stage1 and stage2. Second: If the partition moving succeeds without errors, (so there won't be any data loss, hardware error, etc.) then YES, any such boot problems could be solved from a live CD. Third: When you move your partitions make sure to keep some space unallocated at the beginning of your drive for the bootloader's stuff and for proper disk alignment, it is the best practice if your first partition starts at 1MiB, which is 2048 sectors if your disk uses 512byte sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Ubuntu live as you can use GParted live. GParted has things like testdisk installed by default, but it's available in Ubuntu too. In this case you don't need those extras anyway. Ubuntu has it by default, including gparted.